# remove vertical line action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i want to remove the signed below line from the action bar, how i can do that?

this is my action bar:

[image]

this is my menu.xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/foo2"
        android:icon="@drawable/foo2"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/foo2"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/foo"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/foo"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/foo1"
        android:icon="@drawable/foo1"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/foo1"/>

</menu>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a new style inside

> styles.xml

for your Toolbar and add the "divider" attribute as null.

```
<style name="MyCoolToolbarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
   <item name="divider">@null</item>
</style>
```

And apply this style to your Toolbar like:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    style="@style/MyCoolToolbarStyle"/>
```